# Excel Interop - Set filename before saving

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, excel-interop

Is it possible to set the excel filename before file saving?

I have following simple code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.Sheets[1];

sheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Hello World!";
```

Is it possible to predefine this name before saving?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: [`Workbook.SaveAs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no explicit, foolproof way to do this prior to saving, unfortunately. The closest you could come is to use a template. If you have a template called `FOO.xltx`, you could create your workbook like this:

```
Application.Workbooks.Add "X:\path\to\FOO.xltx"
```

The only quirk is that the name for the new documents will be appended with an incrementing number (`FOO1` the first time, then `FOO2`,`FOO3`, etc.).

To create a template, just create a new document, and when you save it, select `Excel Template (*.xltx)` from the `Save as type` dropdown.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelGunter, that's exactly what I looking for. And one question, is there some way to save the file without that incrementing number at the end: `(FOO1 the first time, then FOO2,FOO3, etc.)`. Thanks.

Comment: No. Excel will append the number automatically in the Save/Save-As dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `saveas` to save the file with the filename you want. Then when the user clicks save it will just update the file that was previously created. Unfortunately there is no other way. Here is the code:

```
workbook.SaveAs(Filename: FILENAMEHERE);
```

Here is the MSDN doc for it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I need.
In this case we have already saved file, and in my case I want to open worksheet as **unsaved** document. In case if I want to close Excel at all I expecting to get this modal: [Image](http://img.in6k.com/screens/EXCEL_2017-05-12_21-59-00.png)

Comment: @RostislavOlshevsky, please clarify your intent about the "Save Changes" dialog.  Do you want to prevent the dialog or force it to display on closing the Workbook even if it has already been saved?

Comment: @TnTinMin Ideally I do not want to save the file at all. I just want to open Excel with data, like in my example above. AND in this case when Excel will propose me to save the file I want to have some predefined filename for saving. (If this is impossible, then regarding to your options, preferable for me to: "force it to display on closing the Workbook even if it has already been saved").

Comment: @RostislavOlshevsky, I'm am still unclear as to what you wish to accomplish as your last comment implies to me you want it saved but not saved at the same time.  If this statement:  "Ideally I do not want to save the file at all" is your goal, then just set `WorkbookReference.Saved = True1.  This will allow you to close the workbook without being prompted assuming that no changes are made between setting that property and closing the workbook.